# Is it a bad habit to omit conjunctions in poetry?

Tags: poetry, sentence-structure, clarity

When writing a verse for a song a lot of times I find it easier to sing if I leave out function words (demonstratives/conjunctions). Is this a bad habit? It seems to cause  lack of clarity but I see it done a lot in poetry. I also get tired of using the word 'and' so often.

```
                Example:
When I went outside my home I had a feeling,
something wasn't right.               (that)
I guess I didn't have the time        (but) 
that is how I almost died             (and)
```

Comment: They don't contribute anything. At best they are an extra syllable to fill a beat. My opinion is it's stronger without them…. Delete 'When", too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just change to periods, especially for eliminating "and". It almost always works fine. It works in all your conjunctive cases:

> When I went outside my home I had a feeling.
>
> Something wasn't right.
>
> I guess I didn't have the time.
>
> That is how I almost died.

It might be a bad *habit*. It is not a bad practice. Don't do it if the meaning is damaged.

If the word is not necessary to the meaning, then brevity beats wordiness.

Answer (score 0):

When writing in general, you can omit words by punctuation:

```
When I went outside my home I had a feeling: something wasn't right. I
guess I didn't have the time... that is how I almost died.
```

From an "acceptability" & literary point of view, this is perfectly fine, because it gives you a (more) unique voice. Given that it's a song you're writing, it's really not a problem, unless this is not the type of voice you want to project.